# PHP and mysql getting the nearest time of today

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I'm storing a date column using time() (php function).
My date column has a int data type since i'm using time() php function.

This is a sample:

```
date
1317957366
1318043891
```

My question is, how would I query or create a logic that would get a result who has a time that is nearest on today's time?

I want to query it via mysql not on the php logic, but if you have suggestion that I should do it on php, then that would also be fine.

Thanks and your help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded. :)

Comment: It's a saying, sorry if that offended you. Eat your own dogfood just means to confront one-self with it's own design. If the designer can not fully deal with the own design, it's often a sign that something has been done wrong. But you can only say, if you specify into which problems you run. E.g. using a date column can help to do date based queries. And you can still return the timestamp of it.

Comment: yep, its okay, no problem. Thanks for your comment anyway. :)

Comment: I think 'eat your own dogfood' means 'use the solution you developed' to refine it and prove that it's better than competition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compare the absolute value of the current time - the stored time, and select the `MIN()` of those:

Perhaps something like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
GROUP BY `date`
HAVING MIN(ABS(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - `date`));
```

If that doesn't work properly, try with a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE  ABS(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - `date`) IN
  SELECT (MIN(ABS(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - `date`)) FROM tbl);
```

Since you have stored the dates as `INT` instead of as MySQL `DATETIME`, you need to convert the current timestamp `NOW()` to a Unix timestamp, then subtract the stored `date`.

Comment: Can't you just do the minus calculation? It's integers, in seconds. No need for the time calculation actually.

Comment: @hakre If they're all in the past, the `ABS()` isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert your date/time to UNIX timestamp and store it in datetime type in mysql. Why? So you can use the various functions that are part of mysql such as year(), month() etc.

http://www.richardlord.net/blog/dates-in-php-and-mysql

Comment: Your answer does not address the question. I think comment to the question would be better place for your advice.

Comment: OP asked for suggestions as well to help work around his issue

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl` ORDER BY ABS(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - `date`) LIMIT 0,1
```

?

You may also try to find row with minimum distance from now with mysql variables:

```
SET @min = 1000000000000, @minid = 0;

SELECT 
  @minid := IF(@min > ABS(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - `date`), id, @minid), 
  @min := IF(@min > ABS(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - `date`), ABS(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - `date`), @min) 
FROM 
  `tbl` ;

SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE id = @minid;
```

You might also calculate value of UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) in PHP (time() gives it) and use it in your queries.